# Creating Salesorder with Vtiger Webservice missing Tax

Tags: web-services, vtiger, vtigercrm

I have the Problem when creating an salesorder with Vtiger Webservice,
The sales order is created but somehow the tax is not added.

I thought it has something to do with  the parameter : hdnTaxType
Cause even if I add this value 'group' it does not apply the Tax to the Salesorder.

I have to manually add The Taxtype 'group' then the system adds the tax.

thats why i tried to add values like:

```
'tax1' => '7.00',
```

and

```
 'group_tax' =>[
        'group_tax_percentage1' => '7.0'
    ],
```

nothing so far did help...
has anybody an Idea what the problem is?

Thank you 
Tobi

```
$salesOrder =[
'lastname' => $customer['lastname'],
'subject' => 'Order from 01.01.1018',
'sostatus' => '1',
'assigned_user_id' => '',
'bill_street' => 'Rechunngsstrasse 123',
'ship_street' =>'Lieferungsstrasse 123',
'productid' => '14x4325',
'currency_id' => '21x1',
'carrier' => 'DHL',
'txtAdjustment' => '13',
'salescommission' => '12',
'exciseduty' => '15',
'hdnTaxType' => 'group',
'tax1' => '7.00',
'hdnS_H_Amount' => '22.22',
'group_tax' =>[
    'group_tax_percentage1' => '7.0'
],

'LineItems' => [
    0 => [
    "taxid" => "33x1",
    'productid'=>'14x6',
    'listprice'=>'20.53',
    'quantity'=>'3',
    'comment' => "Product123"
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Webservices in Vtiger are not complete.
In this case you can register your own webservice that makes your queries, or check the SalesOrder in the after-save event